# Get unique values from Excel spreadsheet for Report Builder

Tags: excel-2010, reportbuilder3.0

I am using an ODBC driver to connect a Report Builder .RDL file to an Excel Spreadsheet.  To get the data, I use:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

For the query, is it possible to modify this to return just unique values of a particular field in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean;

```
SELECT DISTINCT Particular_Field FROM [Sheet1$]
```

That would return only one of each distinct value from `[Sheet1$]` column which name is "Particular_Field";

[image]
[image]